RuntimeError: Given groups=1, expected weight to be at least 1 at dimension 0, but got weight of size [0, 16, 1, 1] instead in YOLOv8 Model Training
I am trying to train a YOLOv8 model using the yolov8n-pose.pt pretrained model with the following configuration in config.yaml:
# Data
path: C:\Users\Denis\OneDrive\Documents\Project\Workout Assistant\data
train: images/train # train images (relative to 'path')
val: images/val # val images (relative to 'path')

# Keypoints
kpt_shape: [8, 0] # [number of keypoints, number of dim]
flip_idx: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] # keypoints to flip

# Classes
names:
    0: starting_pos
    1: lifting

This is my code to train the model
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO('yolov8n-pose.pt')  # load a pretrained model (recommended for training)

model.train(data='config.yaml', epochs=1, imgsz=640)

I get the following error
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, expected weight to be at least 1 at dimension 0, but got weight of size [0, 16, 1, 1] instead

Steps I have tried:

Verified the pretrained model file to ensure it is not corrupted.
Double-checked the config.yaml file for any formatting issues.
Made sure that the dataset paths and class names are correctly specified.

I suspect the issue might be related to the kpt_shape or flip_idx settings, but I am not sure how to resolve it.
Any help or pointers on how to fix this error would be greatly appreciated.
